# Chrome: Site scrolls down automatically

Tags: html, css

I am not sure whether I should post a code snipped because I don't know where exactly the problem might be.

My issue is that our site scrolls automatically in Chrome browsers:
https://www.urban-zweirad.de/shop/fahrradlack/spray-bike/alle-farben/

I will edit my OP and add a code snippet once I narrowed the area where the issue might be.

Thanks!

Comment: We also are not sure why the site scrolls, I at least cannot reproduce this issue. So for us to help you-you need to give us more information.

Comment: When accessing in Chrome 63, it doesn't scroll down automatically. However, are you confusing this with Chrome automatically saving your location on a page so when you reload it, it takes you back there?

Comment: Is it the only site that scrolls? I'd make sure "Page Down" key is not stuck (or any other device control that would scroll down - a faulty mouse wheel, etc...). Also try from another computer. Bottom line being: if we can't reproduce it, we can't figure out what causes it.